# How calculate checksum using 8-bit addition of all bytes in the data structure

Tags: c#

I need to calculate checksum from byte array. Its some serial port packet. I have just this text:

> Checksum is calculated using 8-bit addition of all bytes in the data structure. Overflows are not taken into account (1 byte).

How do 8-bit addition?

Need it in C#.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty weak checksum.

Comment: @Jonas Elfström: Can you explain it more?It is not my protocol is some device protocol which I need to communicate with. But I dont even understand what 8-bit addition is:(

Comment: A file with the bytes {255, 1, 250} will have the same _checksum_ as {10, 90, 150} or {255, 255, 252} and so on.

Comment: But if that's what the protocol says then there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Yes, thats protocol's issue:/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Straight addition? Well, you could iterate over all the bytes pretty easily:

```
public static byte ComputeAdditionChecksum(byte[] data)
{
    byte sum = 0;
    unchecked // Let overflow occur without exceptions
    {
        foreach (byte b in data)
        {
            sum += b;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Alternatively, using LINQ:

```
public static byte ComputeAdditionChecksum(byte[] data)
{
    long longSum = data.Sum(x => (long) x);
    return unchecked ((byte) longSum);
}
```

I'm using `long` to avoid overflowing on a long stream - I'm assuming it will be less than 2<sup>55</sup> bytes :) In practice you'd probably be fine using `int` instead of `long`.

Comment: Can you explain that unchecked syntax?

Comment: @Simon: It puts the arithmetic into an unchecked context: even if the rest of the assembly uses checked arithmetic (i.e. throw OverflowException on arithmetic overflow), this bit of code won't.

Comment: So is I just sumarize all bytes together and if it overflow I will get what?

Comment: @Simon: It will just ignore any higher bits - so 255 + 3 will give 2, for example.

Comment: Another common practice is to exclusive OR the bytes together.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ Solution

```
public static byte CheckSum(byte[] array)
{
     return array.Aggregate<byte, byte>(0, (current, b) => (byte) ((current + b) & 0xff));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#, read data into byte type array, and add all bytes to a seperate byte variable to get checksum result.